# Is floating gradient for a road only relevant to descending parts of the road?

Tags: civil-engineering

Does floating gradient of a road only pertain to the descending part of the road or is it also defined for ascending parts?

Answer (score 1):

Which of the definitions below are you looking for?

"**Road Gradient**" is the rate of **rise or fall** of road level along its length. It is expressed either as the rate of rise or fall to the horizontal distance or as percentage rise or fall. In India usually, former practice is used.

"**Floating Gradient**" means on which a motor vehicle moving with a constant speed **continues to descend** with the same speed without any application of power brakes is called a floating gradient.

[6 Types of Road Gradient](https://civiljungle.com/limiting-gradient/)